# What's the difference between startjobrun and getjobrun- StepFunction with Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws, aws-step-functions

This is the doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-jobs-runs.html#aws-glue-api-jobs-runs-StartJobRun

I have a stepfunction, I want to use it to trigger an existing Glue job and run it, should I use `startjobrun` or `getjobrun`? My Glue job is created by Terraform, I've tried this (see this question: [Glue job succeeded without StepFunction, but failed if it's kicked off by StepFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135124/glue-job-succeeded-without-stepfunction-but-failed-if-its-kicked-off-by-stepfu)) I used `"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",` in stepfunction but the glue job will fail.

My question is for my case, since I've already have my glue job created, should I use `"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:getJobRun.sync",` in the step function? If so, how can I pass the `runId` ?(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-jobs-runs.html#aws-glue-api-jobs-runs-GetJobRun)

```
RunId – Required: UTF-8 string, not less than 1 or more than 255 bytes long, matching the Single-line string pattern.
The ID of the job run.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. we need to use resource `arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync` to start the glue job from [step function task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-glue.html) and we don't need to pass runId. For glue [start-job-run](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glue/start-job-run.html) runId is only required for retry.

```json
 {
         "Type":"Task",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
         "Parameters":{
            "JobName":"my-glue-job",
            "Timeout":60,
            "NotificationProperty":{
               "NotifyDelayAfter":30
            }
         }
      }
```

And [get-job-run](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glue/get-job-run.html) is only to get metadata of a previous execution of a job.